# Test an implementation of an abstract service in an android test project

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have an abstract service that is implemented several times in my app.
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Is it possible to have a custom implementation of this service under the android test project and test this custom implementation ?

Comment: When talking about abstract service, do you mean an [Android Service component](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a Service component. :) I will edit my question to make it clearer.